# DataAdd date part varchar

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where I dynamically obtain a frequency from a long string and want to put it into a DateAdd function..  I understand that the first parameter expecting day year etc will not allow a variable and is expecting a system constant..  Is there any way I can a 'create' a constant or will I have to amend my sql to suit multiple DateAdd functions in a case statement..  Here is the case statement selecting the date part..

```
Select DateAdd(cast
(
    CASE 
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%Type="%', RecurrenceInfo) <> 0 
            THEN SUBSTRING(RecurrenceInfo, PATINDEX('%Type="%', RecurrenceInfo) + 6, 1) 
            ELSE NULL END 
        WHEN '0' THEN 'Day' 
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Week' 
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Month' 
        WHEN '3' THEN 'Year' 
        ELSE NULL 
        END as varchar(5)
),5, MyDate)
```

Comment: Can you perhaps share your code instead of just a small snippet? My guess is this can be handled but a bit different than what you are trying here.

Comment: Hi Sean..  Yes sorry, I added a little bit more just to show what the DateAdd function has to put up with.  I am currently changing my query to accommodate a case statement which choses which one of the 4 options are chosen and then write a DateAdd(Day, 5, MyDate)..

Comment: You can certainly use dynamic sql, or the answer JamieD posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the case you already have and skip the casting

```
Select 
(
    CASE 
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%Type="%', RecurrenceInfo) <> 0 
            THEN SUBSTRING(RecurrenceInfo, PATINDEX('%Type="%', RecurrenceInfo) + 6, 1) 
            ELSE NULL END 
        WHEN '0' THEN DateAdd(day, 5, MyDate) 
        WHEN '1' THEN DateAdd(week, 5, MyDate)
        WHEN '2' THEN DateAdd(month, 5, MyDate)
        WHEN '3' THEN DateAdd(year, 5, MyDate)
        ELSE NULL 
        END 
)
```

Comment: Not that you're wrong, but I think OP was already aware of this option and was looking for others:   "..or will I have to amend my sql to suit multiple DateAdd functions in a case statement.."

Comment: @TabAlleman oh yeah, i see that now.. so answer should just be Yes

Comment: or you could just create a scalar function that handles this if you use it often

Comment: I like the approach in this answer. I mean, you _could_ do what the OP is asking with dynamic SQL, but I don't know if it's worthwhile just to consolidate four `dateadd` calls into one. This is clear and efficient.

Comment: I can't dynamically (I think) as it is expecting a system constant and the statement returns a variable.  The variable puts in the 'Day' and the function expects Day..

Comment: Thank you Jamie I was doing just that :)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it sounded like you weren't sure what a dynamic SQL solution would look like, so I thought I'd post it here for the sake of completeness. I don't actually recommend that you use this answer—JamieD77's is better—but this at least demonstrates the technique in case you encounter a case in the future where using dynamic SQL really is worth the trouble.

```
-- Since I don't have the full context of your original query, I'm just going to use
-- local variables for RecurrenceInfo and MyDate.
declare @RecurrenceInfo varchar(128) = 'Type="2"';
declare @MyDate date = convert(date, getdate());

-- Here is basically the CASE you had in your question, used to assign the value of
-- another variable rather than to evaluate the DATEADD expression directly.
declare @DatePart nvarchar(5) =
    CASE 
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%Type="%', @RecurrenceInfo) <> 0 
            THEN SUBSTRING(@RecurrenceInfo, PATINDEX('%Type="%', @RecurrenceInfo) + 6, 1)
            ELSE NULL END 
        WHEN '0' THEN 'Day' 
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Week' 
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Month' 
        WHEN '3' THEN 'Year' 
        ELSE NULL 
    END;

-- And here's an example of building dynamic SQL. Given the sample data used above,
-- the @Sql variable will hold the following string:
--
--     select dateadd(Month, @Increment, @MyDate);
--
-- I then pass that query to sp_executesql along with some proper parameters for the
-- other two inputs required by DATEADD.
declare @Sql nvarchar(max) = N'select dateadd(' + @DatePart + N', @Increment, @MyDate);';
if @Sql is not null
    exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Increment int, @MyDate date', @Increment = 5, @MyDate = @MyDate;
else
    select null;
```

This is a powerful technique in the right circumstances, but in this case it's probably too much added complexity for too little gain. If you do start playing around with dynamic SQL in general, be sure to do some reading about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Hi Joe..  thanks for your input.  The issue is that you can’t use a variable for the date part of the DateAdd function as it expects a system constant.   You get an error if you try to use a varchar..  Invald type for parameter 1 I think..

Comment: @DerekJee - I'm aware of that. That's the entire point of using dynamic SQL; by the time the `DATEADD` expression is evaluated, my `@DatePart` variable isn't a variable any more; its contents have been written directly into the script so that it will be interpreted as a system constant. Try the code from my answer and you'll see.

Comment: My apologies Joe.  I see what you did there.  It was late when I read your SQL and admit it was also from my phone..  Should have left it for today when I got to work :)..  Thank you that would indeed work.  Thanks for the offering and I will remember that for next time.  Our software uses SQL builders and it does not allow declaring variables and SQL like that.  It is a pain as we could be so much more efficient.. One day.. :)  Thanks again..